# Ubuntu installer usb not bootable created with UNetbootin

Tags: boot, usb-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Windows PC for learning linux staff. So I installed UNetbootin app on my Macbook Pro (Catalina 10.15.3). There is no error during the whole process. However, when I inserted the USB installer on my PC, open the boot menu and select USB name,  it says no bootable device found.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview   (the recommended tool is `etcher`)

Comment: When I have used Unetbootin, it works. Perhaps you did something wrong?

Comment: Why not create your installer USB on Windows if is going to be used on Windows?

Comment: Currently, can not get into the Windows partition and I want to install Ubuntu to replace Windows